# pylint duplicate code false positive

Tags: python, pylint

I have this code in (many) of my Python files for a project.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from pprint import pformat
```

Pylint complains that:

```
==ook:2
==eek:2
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from pprint import pformat (duplicate-code)
```

Which while true is utterly irrelevant. The `from __future__ [...]` lines are there [to prevent compatibility regressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html#prevent-compatibility-regressions) from [Python 2 to Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html). As such, pylint should not complain about them being similar in different files.

Is there a way to stop pytlint doing that?

I know about `pylint: disable=duplicate-code` but that will disable it for the whole file because of the import scope. However, I do not want to disable it for the whole file.

Comment: @tobias_k: `from modile import *` is *really bad practice and should not be used*. On a side note, pylint will complain about that with a `wildcard-import` error. And as you said, `__future__` does not work with wildcard imports.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

## Pylint Similarities Config

Try changing the `ignore-imports` in the [similarities](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html#similarities-checker) section of your [`pylintrc` config file](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#the-next-step).

Default pylintrc:

```
[SIMILARITIES]

# Minimum lines number of a similarity.
min-similarity-lines=4

# Ignore comments when computing similarities.
ignore-comments=yes

# Ignore docstrings when computing similarities.
ignore-docstrings=yes

# Ignore imports when computing similarities.
ignore-imports=no
```

Comment: @Sardathrion Try doing `pylint /path/to/project/ --ignore-imports=no` (*un tested*), but really it is nice to have access to *all* the options from a config file.  If you run `pylint --generate-rcfile` that will print out the default options which you can then alter.  Just keep the file in the directory of your code.

Comment: @Sardathrion or anyone who has a similar issue: We do the same. You can use the argument "--rcfile=tools/pylintrc" when starting pylint from Scons or another script. tools/pylintrc is part of our project tree.

Comment: set `ignore-imports=yes` to ignore the imports.