# fail-under flag does not work with pylint

Tags: pylint, pylintrc

I am running pylint on my code:

```
pylint package --fail-under=8 --rcfile=pylintrc
```

Here is my rcfile:

```
[BASIC]

# Good variable names which should always be accepted, separated by a comma
good-names=i,j,k,e,_

# Private entries do not need documentation
# Yes, private entries must be marked with a single not a double underscore
no-docstring-rgx=_.*

[FORMAT]

# we follow a general practice
max-line-length=79

[MESSAGES CONTROL]

# I0011 - locally disabling ...
# If a pylint message is locally disabled - there is a reason for it. There is no need
# To show a warning

# C0203 - Metaclass method ... should have 'cls' as first argument
# pep8 says otherwise - lets stick with pep8 here

# R1705 - no-else-return] Unnecessary "else" after "return"
# Sometimes else at the end looks clearer, let's allow this.

disable=I0011, C0203, R1705

[REPORTS]

# set the output format. Available formats are text, parseable, colorized and html
output-format=text

# reasonable message template
msg-template=@{line}: [{msg_id} {symbol}] {msg}

[MASTER]

# given that numpy is a C extension it has to be white-listed
# same goes for MySQLdb exceptions
extension-pkg-whitelist=numpy,MySQLdb

[TYPECHECK]

# numpy has a bunch of dynamically created fields invisible for pylint
# they need to be ignored
ignored-modules = numpy
ignored-classes = numpy

[SIMILARITIES]
# Ignore similar imports, see:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206482/pylint-duplicate-code-false-positive
# It is better to disable this on imports, than on the whole file because
# of required imports.
ignore-imports=yes
```

It seems that `--fail-under` has no effect and it does not exits even score is below 8. I believe this feature is relatively new and I have seen the documentation on it as well:

http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html. Can't seems to figure out why it is not working. Any lead is this regard will be helpful.

This is my pylint version:

```
pylint 2.8.2
astroid 2.5.6
Python 3.6.1 (default, Jul 13 2020, 15:20:59) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59)]
```